# Do I need to migrate to DCR based log ingestion

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics

I got this mail from Microsoft stating to migrate to DCR based log ingestion

*Data Collector API will be retired on 14 September 2026 – transition to DCR-based custom log ingestion.*

*You’re receiving this email because you currently use the Data Collector API for ingestion of custom logs to Azure Monitor logs. On 14 September 2026, we’ll retire Data Collector API for ingesting custom logs to Azure Monitor logs. Before that date, you’ll need to transition to the Data Collection Rules based log ingestion API that provides all the functionality of the Data Collector API, as well as new ones, including:*

- *Secure token-based authentication*
- *Full control over the shape of the destination table*
- *Ability to filter and transform data during ingestion*

***Required action***

*To avoid ingestion errors and data loss, transition to the DCR-based Log Ingestion API before 14 September 2026. Data Collector API endpoints will become unavailable after that date.*

But I have a question.

I am not sending Logs but I am sending a custom (small) json class. And write it directly to
the "The Azure Log Analytics HTTP Data Collector API". (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/create-request?source=docs)

Now it's not really clear to me if this method will stop at that date or if it will still function but no longer for the standard logs (Traces etc).

Anybody who can shed a light on this ?

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/logs/custom-logs-migrate.md)